# htaccess redirect .co.uk to .com for all pages

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic

Im migrating my website from the .co.uk to the .com but need to setup a 301 redirect so all of the individual pages will still be routed properly.

ie i want http://www.mydomain.co.uk/shopping/product1 to go to http://www.mydomain.com/shopping/product1

I have done this before but for the life of me cannot remember how.

many thanks

paul

Answer (score 27):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects both the www and non-www for **mydomain.co.uk** to **www.mydomain.com**.

Comment: perfect! how to take care of www and non-www for the .com as well? so that all four scenarios (www & non-www, .co.uk and .com) all go to the same www.mydomain.com?

Comment: is it sufficient just to add a second RewriteCond after your first one ... like so:

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]

Comment: @hawbsl: Above condition makes `www` optional so it will serve both `www.mydomain.co.uk` and `mydomain.co.uk` domains in request.

Comment: @hawbsl Not sure if it's relevant in your case, but since the original question was apparently related to a webshop (judging by the URLs), you might still want to specify if your question is about regular ole `HTTP` or also involves secure connections (`HTTPS`) at some point.

Answer (score 3):

To redirect any (sub-)domain other than `mydomain.com`, use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Might be useful if you have other domains pointing to the same website.

It also redirects the `www.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished using a simple rewrite placed in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This might be a bit aggressive. Consider if the user has other domains they do not wish to redirect.

Comment: The RewriteCond of this rule set will limit the RewriteRule to only affect the mydomain.co.uk host.

Comment: No, you are negating the condition (`!`). So this reads anything that's not **mydomain.co.uk**.

Comment: Whoops. You're right. My answer admittedly involved a copy+paste, and in my haste I missed that.